# RequireJS and legacy in page code

Tags: javascript, jquery, requirejs

I've started using RequireJS and it works very well for new code.
However we have a large portion of the app that uses in page javascript blocks that are generated serverside.
I was wondering if anyone knew what the best approach is for bridging this. I'd prefer not to rewrite all the JavaScript a full client side app as it would take forever. So my question is, is there a way of running the in page stuff once RequireJS has loaded, and is there a clean way of exposing libraries described in Require to the legacy code?

i.e.

How could you adapt this to run once require had loaded:

```
<script type="text/javascript">alert($('#somediv').html())</scipt>
```

Note the jquery dependancy.

Answer (score 1):

I'm really wary about what I'm about to suggest, as I think this is an unfortunate problem of things being incorrectly designed originally; you're sort of running against the basic way Javascript works. I'd really prefer to think of this kind of issue as "job security" for the person assigned to re-make this stuff as outside-of-HTML code.

But if you want to hear it, I do have a possible solution that uses `eval`. For that alone, I think I'm going to be downvoted, and not without good reason. I haven't even tested this (except for the 'script with alternate type' and its selection), but seeing this question had two upvotes, no answer, I figure I'll suggest it. So, you're going to have to evaluate it with its potential security risks.

Start by replacing in-page scripts with this:

```
<script type="text/postRequireScript">alert($('#somediv').html())</script>
```

Since the browser doesn't know what a "postRequireScript" is, it won't load it. Once requirejs has loaded, run this script (you could also add a 'class' to these scripts to make selecting all of them easier)

```
$("script[type='text/postRequireScript']").each(function() {
  var scriptContent = $(this).text();
  // highly recommend you do at least some sanitization on scriptContent, if you know
  // what sort of things to expect from it.
  eval(scriptContent);
  this.type = 'text/completedScript'; // prevent script from being re-run.
});
```

This would need to run each time you're adding HTML that could have a script in it.

Comment: That's an interesting approach that I hadn't thought of.